# How to make this JSON file

Tags: java, json

I need to make a JSON file which is going to be read in by a Java-class.
I think i can manage the reading by Java if i get the JSON right.

The JSON is going to hold around 50 records of the following data type:

- imageURI (Holding the String URI to an image file)
- question (Holding a String containing the question)
- array (Holding 4 instances of String for answer options)
- integer (Holding the value for the right answer in the array above)

I need help to make the boilerplate/skeleton showing how the JSON should look for holding the values described above.

It needs to be complete so i can just plug in my values and save the file on disk.

Thanks for any help offered :)

Comment: Look at gson library.

Comment: it's not that difficoult task.. read a little how the standard works https://www.json.com/ and DIY ;)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

A structure like this should be sufficient. Make sure to check your json with http://jsonlint.com/ in case you run into trouble.

```
[
    {
        "imageURI": "http://example2.abc",
        "question": "Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet...",
        "answers": [
             "String 1",
             "String 2",
             "String 3",
             "String 4"
         ],
        "correct": 0
    },
    {
        "imageURI": "http://example.abc",
        "question": "Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet...",
        "answers": [
             "String 1",
             "String 2",
             "String 3",
             "String 4"
         ],
        "correct": 2
    },
    ...
]
```